# Azure - Website calling API - The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed

Tags: asp.net, azure, cors, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-apps

I have a website in Azure that is calling an API (also in Azure).

When I published the website and the API, and tried them a few times, I could GET data, but not POST or DELETE. It was saying something that 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header was not set.

So I started fiddle with the CORS (*I already had in the controller*

`[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "GET")]`

*, and in WebApiConfig*

`var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
 config.EnableCors(cors);`

*according to this documentation, which used to work when I was running the services locally
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api* )

Now, after nothing worked and I reversed to the original state (when GET was working), I keep getting this errors in the console in Chrome:

> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.

and this in Firefox:

> Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘(null)’

I do not have access to .htaccess . I checked if I have other CORS related code in the services I mentioned and from what I can tell, it's only the stuff described above. I also tried to comment the code above and the errors still remain the same.

Comment: Try only one "*" in the EnableCorsAttribute?

Comment: Do you have any update?

Comment: @TomSun-MSFT I left only `config.EnableCors();` in App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs and used `[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]` in the controllers (after everything worked out, I changed the "origins" from "*" to the address of the website that uses the API). Here's another guide I found useful: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/fix-to-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-or-w/

Comment: I am glad you have worked it out . Do you have a try just set it from azure portal? Base on my experence, it will also work.

Comment: If you add your soluation to answer that will help more communities.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a try to config it on the Azure Portal? If not, please have a try to config it on your Azure WebAPI site. More details please refer to the screenshot.
We also can get the related info from the Azure [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-api/app-service-api-cors-consume-javascript).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize this was overriding settings from in the app. Odd behavior when this isn't enabled in the portal but configurations are otherwise valid in the app.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing exactly this same error but in my case the solution was in removing from the web.config these lines to fix it.

```
<httpProtocol>
 <customHeaders>
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
 </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Answer (score -1):

I left **only** `config.EnableCors();` in App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs.

And used `[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]` in the controllers.

*Note: after everything worked out, I changed the "`origins`" from "`*`" to the address of the website that uses the API.*

Here's another guide I found useful: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/fix-to-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-or-w/